# JsTree returns "invalid JSON" error

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I'm trying to make a Jstree, the code for it is the following:

```
$(function () {
$("#groups")
    .jstree({ 
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "cookies", "dnd", "search", "types", "contextmenu" ],

        "json_data" : {
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : base_url+"/json",
                "data" : function (n) {
                    return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };
                },
                error: function(e,b,d){alert(d);}

            }
        },

        "types" : {
            "max_depth" : -2,
            "max_children" : -2,
            "valid_children" : [ "drive" ],
            "types" : {
                "default" : {
                    "valid_children" : "none",
                    "icon" : {
                        "image" : "./file.png"
                    }
                },
                "folder" : {
                    "valid_children" : [ "default", "folder" ],
                    "icon" : {
                        "image" : "./folder.png"
                    }
                }

            }
        },

        "ui" : {
            "initially_select" : [ "node_4" ]
        },
        "core" : { 
            "initially_open" : [ "node_2" , "node_3" ] 
        }
    });

});
```

This is the Json I get back from the Ajax call

```
[
{
    "data" : "Genral ",
    "attr" : {
        "id" : "8"
    },
    "state" : "open",
    "children" : [
        {
            "data" : "onec ",
            "attr" : {
                "id" : "16"
            },
            "state" : "close"
        },
        {
            "data" : "onec2",
            "attr" : {
                "id" : "21"
            },
            "state" : "close"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "data" : "Stuff ",
    "attr" : {
        "id" : "9"
    },
    "state" : "open",
    "children" : [
        {
            "data" : "one9 ",
            "attr" : {
                "id" : "23"
            },
            "state" : "close"
        },
        {
            "data" : "bababa ",
            "attr" : {
                "id" : "24"
            },
            "state" : "close"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I get an Error saying 'Invalid JSON:....', how do I solve this?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON returned is valid. If i were to take a guess - maybe you need to specify the type. EG:

```
 $("#groups").jstree({
        "json_data": {
            "ajax": {
                "type": "POST",
                "url": base_url+"/json",
                "data": function (n) { return { id: n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0} }
            }
        },
```

Comment: didn't work, it's already calling the Ajax since the error message shows me the invalid json... so it DOES get the Json but for some reason sees it as invalid

Comment: You can validate your json at http://www.jsonlint.com/. The only difference between your json_data: and mine is that I assign a type and dont include the error. I assume you've put a break point on your url page to ensure that is the json you're getting back? If all of that is correct you might want to make your way to the jstree google groups - they're most active there and usually answer questions within the hour. http://groups.google.com/group/jstree

Comment: update (long time coming) -> the JSON was invalid, but this one fixed another problem i had.

Answer (score 0):

I guess *json_data* rather needs to be an [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call:

```
"json_data" : $.ajax({
    "dataType": "json",
    "url" : base_url+"/json",
    "data" : function (n) {
        return { id : n.attr ? n.attr("id") : 0 };
    },
    error: function(e,b,d){alert(d);}
})
```